# Why Compiled C programm is OS dependent

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I learned that c-compiler translate the high level c code to machine level code, which is according to the instruction encoding of underlying processor which makes that compile code that processor dependent. Which is i understood.
But why then this compiled c program is OS dependent. My question is why can't two machine having similar processor(same instruction encoding) with different OS run same compiled c file, compiled on any one of them.
I understand that LINUX cant run WINDOWS's .exe and vice versa and every OS has different system call mechanism, but these are OS level things, why these things makes that machine level(instruction level) compiled file dependent on them.
Please help me..

Comment: because Linux executables use the ELF binary format, and Windows uses PE or COFF binary formats. so you're already dealing with Coke v.s. Pepsi before you even get into the realm of system calls. e.g. what's the system call at the assembly level to trigger "exit"? LInux and Unix will both use different software interrupts, function names, blah blah blah.

Comment: Because the C program needs to communicate with the OS, and they have different interfaces. There is no 'standard' OS interface. Otherwise, they would all be the *same* OS.

Comment: Moreover a program often is using the services provided by the OS. And, as you can guess, different OSs providing different services.

Comment: @WeatherVane: well, actually, (http://well.actually.cat/ http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html) there is a standard OS interface, it's called POSIX, for Portable Operating System Interface. Of course, it only covers the API, not the ABI, and not everyone follows it.

Comment: @ninjalj good point, but it's **a standard** not **the standard**. Not sure of the relevance of your link since *POSIX* is not mentioned and it only quotes your good self.

Comment: @WeatherVane: the link was to point out that I was _well-actually_'ing you (and, in the process, acting like a patronizing douchebag). That's my self-deprecating sense of humour.

Comment: @ninjalj well my bad then i forgot about posix

Answer (score 0):

The compiled machine code itself would indeed execute on all operating systems running on the same architecture (assuming the binary files themselves were in a format compatible with, each OS, which they generally aren't - the executable files aren't just instructions one after another, so you would already have trouble getting each OS to read your machine code).

However, what could a program using no OS-specific calls accomplish other than taking up processor cycles? For instance, the C standard library can not be implemented without OS-specific calls (e.g., how would you do `malloc`, or `fopen`, or indeed any I/O). So the portable program could not use any library functions, and the OS would almost certainly prevent it from directly accessing the hardware, or memory belonging to other programs (a simple OS like DOS might be an exception).

Comment: Yeah I understand that, suppose i want my code to do some socket I/O i need system call or OS call to do it. But lets say my compiled code will just inform(using some instruction or flag) to OS that at some point of instructions i need socket I/O and OS will start socket I/O for me. Now that "inform" mechanism(instruction of flag) can be common to all OS, and how to handle that socket I/O happens is that OS's business.. can't it be like that??

Comment: @user3690370 Yes, it could in theory be like that, but in practice it isn't. The compatibility is at source code level, e.g., you can use POSIX and C standard functions and compile a binary for most OS with minor or no changes. Some *nix systems do support running binaries for certain other OS for the same platform, and early versions of OS X support running classic Mac OS binaries, but this typically requires installing any libraries in duplicate.